# Checking if an input is a particular type and in a particular range

Tags: c++, while-loop

I'm trying to test the input a user enters so my program cannot break. The line i'm using is:

```
while (check != 0){
    cout << "Please enter a number 1 - 4 (area of: circle, rectangle, triangle or quit)" << endl;
    cin >> response;


    if ((isdigit(response)) && ((response >= 1) && (response <= 4))){
        check = 0;

    }
    else{
        cout << "You did not enter a valid digit (1 - 4)" << endl;
        check = 1;
    }

} // End of while loop
```

What i'm trying to do is check if the input is both a digit (integer specifically) and in the range of 1 and 4. For some reason, every value I enter is consider invalid using this method. What should I change or do alternatively to get the desired outcome i'm looking for? (So that it will check if the input is an integer and if that integer is between 1 and 4 (including 1 and 4)).

Comment: What's actually going wrong with your approach?

Comment: What is `check`? What is `response`? And you know that a stream can be used in a [boolean expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) to check if it succeeded or not? The last bit means you could declare `response` as an `int` and do something like `if (!(cin >> response) || !is_between(response, 1, 4))`.

Comment: Why not just say `while (1)`, and then when the user input is valid, use the `break` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `response` is of type `char`, you need to use the character constants `'1'` and `'4'`, not the integer constants `1` and `4`.

```
if ((isdigit(response)) && ((response >= '1') && (response <= '4'))){
```

Comment: Oh thanks. I completely forgot isdigit is for char values. I'll √ the question in 10min.

Answer (score 0):

`if (response >= '1' && response <= '4')` is all you need. If the character that was input is in the correct range it has to be a digit, so the test for `isdigit` is not needed. Nor are the redundant parentheses.